# How to make laptop not to sleep when closing the lid, but additional display is connected?

Tags: laptop, display, sleep, lid

I have my laptop with Windows 10 connected to additional display, and sometimes want to work just with additional display on. Yes, I can set laptop not to sleep on lid close, but I want to have this option only when laptop is connected to additional display. Is there any ideas how to reach that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to do this based on externall monitor connection, at least as far as I know. 
The best you could do is have 2 power settings, a monitor one and a normal on that you switch back and forth between.

Comment: thank you for an answer, this is pretty good idea, but still not perfect